# Equation of tangent on Cartesian plane given center and radius of a circle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

If I have a generic circle with radius $r$ and center $(h, k)$, and a tangent line with point of tangency $(x, y)$, can you give me the equation of the tangent line? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I was taught to get tangents to conic sections in high school, half a century ago. If you want to get the tangent at the point $(x_0,y_0)$, you take the equation of the conic, and replace "half" of the $x$'s by $x_0$ and "half" of the $y$'s by $y_0$.

In this case, the equation of the curve is $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$, so the tangent at $(x_0,y_0)$ will be $(x_0-h)(x-h) + (y_0-k)(y-k)=r^2$.

A little algebra, using the fact that $x_0^2 + y_0^2 = r^2$, shows that this can also be written in the form $(x_0 -h)(x-x_0) + (y_0 -k)(y-y_0) = 0$.

This works with any conic section curve, and it gives you tangent planes of quadric surfaces, too.

Of course, you can apply the same process even if the point $(x_0,y_0)$ doesn't lie on the curve. In this case, the line you get is called the [polar line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) of the point. It just happens that, for any point lying on the curve, the polar line is the tangent at the point.

I'm curious -- do they still teach this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Let the point of tangency be $P=(x_0, y_0)$. If the center of the circle is at $C=(h,k)$, then the line $\overleftrightarrow{CP}$ is perpendicular to tangent line at the point $P$. The slope of the line $\overleftrightarrow{CP}$ is $\dfrac{y_0-k}{x_0-h}$, so the slope of the tangent line is $m=-\dfrac{x_0-h}{y_0-k}$.

The equation of the tangent line is therefore

$$y - y_0 = -\dfrac{x_0-h}{y_0-k}(x-x_0)$$

Just to satisfy my own curiosity, I want to write this equation is standard form.

\begin{align}
   y - y_0 &= -\dfrac{x_0-h}{y_0-k}(x-x_0) \\
   (y_0-k)y - (y_0-k)y_0 &= -(x_0-h)x + (x_0-h)x_0 \\
   (x_0-h)x + (y_0-k)y &= (x_0-h)x_0 + (y_0-k)y_0 \\
   (x_0-h)x + (y_0-k)y &= x_0^2 + y_0^2 -h x_0 - k y_0\\   
\end{align}